# jQuery Mobile App cross Domain issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, https, cross-domain

I want to develop a jQuery mobile app that uses web service to fetch data from website. I have a login page.I want to communicate with an https page(say https://mysite.com/validate.php?username=user&pass=pwd). When I try to access the page using ajax I am getting error.When i use http url i am getting JSON response(may be cross domain problem).My question is can we solve this problem by making login page also https. If so how?. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could force https with the following mod rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I assume you are on an apache server. In that case make a .htaccess file in the web root with that text inside.